# Qt external libraries include inside custom library

Tags: c++, qt, shared-libraries

I have a Qt project that looks like this:

```
myLib/
   myLib.pro
   (some *.h, *.cpp)
myProject/
   myProject.pro
   (some *.h, *.cpp)
```

myLib.pro includes some external libraries using `INCLUDEPATH +=` and `LIBS +=` (for example Eigen)
myProject depends on myLib, so I added the dependency with the Qt wizard which added to myProject.pro something like:

```
unix|win32: LIBS += -L$$OUT_PWD/../myLib/ -lmyLib
INCLUDEPATH += $$PWD/../myLib
DEPENDPATH += $$PWD/../myLib
```

The problem is when I compile the library it works, but when I try to compile the project I get errors like

> `Eigen/Core: No such file or directory`

because in my project's source file I include some headers from my own libraries which include some headers from an external libraries.

The only solution I know to solve this is to copy/paste all the includes and links from myLib.pro to myProject.pro also. Is there a better way to do this?
I was thinking maybe having a *.pri for each of the external libraries and include these *.pri in both *.pro. But this is not completely satisfying.

EDIT:
I forgot to mention myLib is a shared library

Answer (score 0):

The first thing I would check is that you actually need these headers in myProject. Think carefully about the API of myLib and what that requires. If you are passing in Eigen types and matrices then yes you will need to add them to your include path and a .pri file might help with this. You may also want to consider putting something like Eigen in a pre-compiled header. If not then you should look at rearranging your header files to make sure they are only pulling in what is needed for that particular header and move as many includes as possible into your source files. Again this will dramatically help with your compile times.

I don't think you mention whether `myLib` is a shared or static library. If it is a static library then yes you will need to link `myProject` to everything that `myLib` depends upon but the flip side is that deployment becomes easier and function calls into that library become more efficient. If it is a shared library then you only need to link to that library.